# Remove Object with loop or NSPredicate (JSON - Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, json, object

My json I have a key called drawDate, and if the date is negative I would delete the objects with a "for" loop and then with NSPredicate as I did for the "Status" for example, how to do ? Thank you

(I do not use NSObject class)

My code :

```
- (void)fetchEntries
{
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager GET:API_V3_CHANNEL_URL parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

        NSDictionary *searchDict = responseObject;

        // 541068f7a30379d0d44d6e45

        // On filtre le json
        NSPredicate *firstNamePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status == %@", @"LIVE"];
        NSPredicate *lastNamePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status == %@", @"PAUSE"];

        NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[firstNamePredicate, lastNamePredicate]];

        self.readArray = [[searchDict objectForKey:@"CONTESTS"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:compoundPredicate];

        NSDate *date = [self.readArray valueForKey:@"drawDate"];

        // Delete object with loop (for) or NSPredicate

        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "negative" date? Do you mean a date before current moment? Why don't you just extend your `compoundPredicate` with `drawDate > %@, [NSDate date]`?

Comment: @Sulthan Yes that's exactly what I want to do but I do not know how to integrate it into a NSPredicate

Comment: Define "Negative date" ? Show an example of "valid" and "negative" date. If it's an int, `drawDate.integerValue > 0` to your predicate?

Comment: `NSPredicate *datePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"drawDate > %@", [NSDate date]];`

Comment: @Sulthan Crash, my code : NSDate *date = [self.readArray valueForKey:@"drawDate"];
        
        NSPredicate *dateCheck = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"drawDate > %@", [NSDate date]];

Comment: @Larme Yes but how to integrate it into my NSPredicate?

Comment: First of all, I don't think that `date` is really valid. That's just a bad cast. Again, if you could show a little of your JSON (the real value look alike), that could be helpful.

Comment: @Larme My json : https://test-srv.mediaswapp.com/json/contest/app4phone/fr/iphone/contests.json

Comment: @Sulthan It works but the problem is that the predicate appears and does not remove the object me, it's the opposite that I wanted